# C# Generic classes structure with generic inner object with other type

Tags: c#, oop, generics

I am trying to build **generic classes structure that will be used by mailing service**.

I want to have predefined classes inheriting from an abstract class that will enforce some properties (*subject, template file name etc.*)
The most important part of every inheriting class however, should be `T InnerObject` object used by `TemplateModel` property, that will fetch certain properties, assign them to properly names keys, so that they can be later used inside of e-mail template.

---

What I have so far:

1. `EmailService` class

```
public class EmailService : IEmailService
{
    // Rest of service code

    public async Task SendAsync<T, Y>(Y innerModel, string toRecipient)
            where T : EmailMessageBase<Y>, new()
            where Y : new()
    {
        var emailObject = new T();

        var htmlBody = await GetEmailHtmlBodyAsStringAsync<Y>(emailObject);
        await _sender.SendMessageAsync(emailObject.EmailSubject, htmlBody, toRecipient);
    }

    private async Task<string> GetEmailHtmlBodyAsStringAsync<Y>(EmailMessageBase<Y> emailObject)
        where Y : new()
    {
        var assemblyFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

        var templateTextPath = Path.Combine(assemblyFolder, "Emails/Templates", emailObject.TemplateFileName);
        var templateText = File.ReadAllText(templateTextPath);

        if (_parser.TryParse(templateText, out var templateResult, out var error))
        {
            var context = new TemplateContext(emailObject.TemplateModel);

            return await templateResult.RenderAsync(context);
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Error while rendering e-mail body from template: {error}");
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

2. Classes structure

```
public abstract class EmailMessageBase<T>
    where T : new()
{
    public string EmailSubject => $"HappyService - [{Subject}]";
    protected abstract string Subject { get; }
    public abstract string TemplateFileName { get; }
    public abstract object TemplateModel { get; }
    protected T InnerObject { get; }
}

public class AccountCreated : EmailMessageBase<UserRegisteredResponse>
{
    protected override string Subject => "Welcome to HappyService!";
    public override string TemplateFileName => "AccountCreated.html";

    public override object TemplateModel => new
    {
        UserName = InnerObject.UserName
    };
}

public class UserRegisteredResponse
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegisteredDateTimeUtc { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
}
```

This does not work, as I have a null reference expception at `InnerObject` (which seems logical, even without running a code), but this is the closest I could get to the final solution.

Additionally - I am still forced to pass Y parameter, which seems wrong, as `SendAsync()` method should not look "two levels down" to generic types parameters (?).

Is there a way to setup mentioned classes to be able to use mentioned method like: `SendAsync<T>(? innerModel, string toRecipient)` ?

Then, if `T` would be i.e `AccountCreated : EmailMessageBase<UserRegisteredResponse>`, the compiler will shout at me when I pass anything other than `UserRegisteredResponse` as `innerModel` parameter.

Comment: So what value should `InnerObject` store, if not null? You never created any `Y`s or `UserRegisteredResponse`s as far as I can see.

Comment: Do you perhaps want to do something like `var emailObject = new T(innerModel);` in `SendAsync`?

Comment: `T InnerObject { get; }` If the property is readonly, you will need to assign it in the constructor, or as an initialiser. Or just make it abstract, so the child class can decide how to store the internal value.

Comment: @Sweeper - I am trying to use SendAsync() method with only ONE generic type parameter provided `SendAsync<WorkItemCommentedOn>()`. Why do I have to pass another type -> `SendAsync<WorkItemCommentedOn,UserRegisteredResponse>()`. That's actually the main question in my post.
Also, as far as I know, it's impossible to call something like `new T(innerModel)` in C#